# $http.get() is not working with Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've been trying to access some data from my firebase database through Cloud Functions for Firebase.
I am making a $http.get() call to my function but I am getting an error. The function sends back a JSON object after execution.
Here is my code snippet:

```
     var url = 'https://us-central1-pickdro-f7249.cloudfunctions.net/calculateFare?clientId=clientId&distance=5';
    var trustedUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
    console.log(trustedUrl);
    $http({
         method: 'JSONP',
         url: trustedUrl
    }).
    then(function onSuccess(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }, function onError(status) {
        console.log(status)
    });
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's the error? Does the response log anything?

Comment: what our log says ?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :{"clientId":"clientId","distance":"14.9","fare":181.8}  

I don't see what's the error in this @JorgeValle

Comment: The JSON looks fine. Is that first colon just part of the error message, or part of the actual JSON?

Comment: @JorgeValle the colon is the part of the error message, It's referring to the colons inside the JSON

Comment: Try running the whole JSON through a validator and report back.